# Understanding the behavior of np.bitwise_and

Tags: python, numpy, bitwise-operators

Consider the following example code:

```
rand2 = np.random.rand(10)
rand1 = np.random.rand(10)
rand_bool = np.asarray([True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True], dtype=np.bool)
a = np.bitwise_and(rand1 > .2, rand2 < .9, rand_bool)
print(a)
b = np.bitwise_and(rand1 < .2, rand2 > .9, rand_bool)
print(a)
```

The output on my computer (Python 3.4) is:

```
[ True False  True  True  True False  True  True  True  True]
[False False False False False False False False False False]
```

I don't understand why assigning another `bitwise_and` to the variable `b` changes the variable `a`. Also a test `a is b` returns `True`. Can anybody explain this behavior to me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument of [`bitwise_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) is optional.  It specifies an output array in which to store the result.  When it is given, it is also the return value of `bitwise_and`.  You have used the same array, `rand_bool`, in both calls of `bitwise_and`, so they are both writing their result to that array and returning that value.

In other words, your code is equivalent to this:

```
rand_bool[:] = np.bitwise_and(rand1 > .2, rand2 < .9)  # Put the result in rand_bool
a = rand_bool   # Assign a to rand_bool

rand_bool[:] = np.bitwise_and(rand1 > .2, rand2 < .9)  # Put the result in rand_bool
b = rand_bool   # Assign b to rand_bool
```